# What "former requirement" certainly has no place in estoppel?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

Screenshot on the left: [*O'Sullivan & Hilliard's The Law of Contract*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSullivan-Hilliards-Law-Contract-Janet/dp/0198807821/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (2018 8 ed). p. 328.
Right: Paul Davies. [*JC Smith's The Law of Contract* (2018 2 ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Smiths-Law-Contract-Paul-Davies/dp/0198807813/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). p. 466.

> [image]

To what does the red underline refer? It can't be the green, as the green appears in Davies's definition of estoppel.

Comment: You should transcribe the words in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'The former' means the first part of the green:

> **the mistake ‘must be one calculated to
>   benefit’ the non-mistaken party** <s>or to be detrimental to the mistaken party</s>

Estoppel works to prevent harm to the misled, not to prevent benefit to the misleader.

Comment: Yes the principle is meant to prevent harm to the misled, but the sentence is focusing on the word "calculated", meaning planned in that case.

Comment: @Putvi promissory estoppel requires knowingly misleading someone - calculation is inherently part of that.